# Space of linear and bounded operators is Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that if $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ is a normed space and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ is a Banach space then $(B(X,Y),\|\cdot\|_{op})$ is a Banach space.

$B(X,Y) = \{T\colon X\to Y : T$ is bounded and linear$\}$

What I did :

Let $\|x\|_X \le 1$ and $\|T\|_{op} = \sup\{\|T(x)\|_Y\ : \|x\|_X \le 1\}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|T_n\|_{op}$ is convergent i.e. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ is absolute convergent series in $B(X,Y)$

We have $\|T_n(x)\|_Y \le \|T_n\|_{op}$ from definition

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|T_n\|_{op}$ is convergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|T_n(x)\|_Y$ is convergent too.

Since $(Y,\|\cdot \|_Y)$ is a Banach space $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n(x)$ is convergent.

Let $S_k= \sum_{n=1}^k T_n(x)$

$\exists y \in Y$ such that $S_k \to y$

I've stuck in that point. How must I pursue? I think there are some mistakes or unnecessary things. Could you please fix me? How can I show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ is convergent in $B(X,Y)$?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably easier to take a Cauchy sequence in $B(X,Y)$ and show directly that it must converge.

Comment: What are $T_n$? If you are using definition you should start with a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @A.Γ. An equivalent characterisation of Banach spaces is that they are precisely the spaces where all absolutely convergent series are convergent. That's what the OP is trying to check.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thanks I know but it’s my homework and I have to do it in this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have established that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_nx$ converges for all $x \in X$. Define a linear map $T : X \to Y$ with $$Tx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_nx$$

For $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in X$ we have

$$\left\|Tx - \sum_{n=1}^N T_nx\right\| = \left\|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty T_nx\right\| \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \|T_nx\| \le \left(\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \|T_n\|\right)\|x\|$$
taking the supremum over $\|x\| = 1$ we get

$$\left\|T - \sum_{n=1}^N T_n\right\| \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \|T_n\| \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} 0$$

so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n = T$ with respect to the operator norm.

Furthermore, let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left\|T - \sum_{n=1}^N T_n\right\| \le 1$. We have

$$\|T\| \le \left\|T - \sum_{n=1}^N T_n\right\| + \left\|\sum_{n=1}^N T_n\right\| \le 1 + \sum_{n=1}^N \|T_n\| < +\infty$$

so $T$ is bounded.

We conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ converges to an element of $B(X,Y)$ so $B(X,Y)$ is a Banach space.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Should I show $T$ is linear?

Comment: @user519955 It is pretty clear:
$$T(\alpha x + \beta y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n(\alpha x + \beta y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha T_nx + \beta T_ny) = \alpha \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_nx + \beta \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_ny = \alpha Tx + \beta Ty$$
but it should be at least stated, yes.

Comment: thank you so much. Have a nice day